# MVC Just populate viewbag once, between page default action result and httppost

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Let's say I populate a viewbag object in my page action result like this

```
public ActionResult MiEmployeeDetails()
{
    var employees = _db.geo_employees.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.name,
        Text = x.name
    }).ToList();
    ViewBag.Employees = employees;
    return View();
}
```

and then populate in my view as such

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Employees") %>
```

That's fine but then when I hit the submit button and it goes to Httppost Action Result i.e.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MiEmployeeDetails(FormCollection fc)
{
    return View();
}
```

I get a null reference exception on my viewbag option. So in my Httppost action result do I also need to reset the viewbag object created in my original page load action result ?

Comment: ViewBags are not sent back to the server on post. If you want it back you've got to put it in your model/form

Answer (score 0):

Each request is completely independent.  You need to reinitialize all view data if you call the view again from a post.  The only exemption is data that is sent from the Client during the post